# ESLint object destructuring new line formats function

Tags: javascript, eslint

I want to be able to format my code something like this:

```
const {
    header, 
    note, 
    otherStuff
} = labels;

const { thisDestructuredObject } = _.get(labels,`some.thing.here`,`some.default.value`);
```

Eslint formats it like this:

```
const {
    header, note, otherStuff
} = labels;

const { thisDestructuredObject } = _.get(labels,
    `some.thing.here`,
    `some.default.value`);
```

Yet, I have both rules set:

```
"function-paren-newline": ["error", { "minItems": 4 }],
"object-curly-newline": [
    "error",
    {
        "ObjectExpression": { "multiline": true, "minProperties": 2 },
        "ObjectPattern": { "multiline": true, "minProperties": 2 },
        "ImportDeclaration": "never",
        "ExportDeclaration": { "multiline": true, "minProperties": 3 }
    }
]
```

I have presets enabled for `React` and the recommended settings for ESLint.
Also, plugins for `React` and `React-hooks` are set.

Anyone ever tried to do something like this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There isn't a built-in rule for this currently, but there is an [open proposal for it](https://github.com/eslint/eslint/issues/9259). The [eslint-plugin-putout](https://github.com/coderaiser/putout/tree/master/packages/eslint-plugin-putout) package has a couple rules for doing this until it's baked it.

Comment: Thank you! I switched in the end to a true code formatter (Prettier) for these things and use ESLint more for finding possible bugs.

Comment: Any updates on this after long time? Is there a built in rule for that now?

Comment: I don't think so, the linked proposal has been closed.